# RC Circuit equation form/format

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a question about finding the voltage across a circuit element when the circuit contains a energy storage element.

When is it appropriate to use \$V_0e^{t/RC}\$ and when is it appropriate to use KCL, KVL and plug them in to each other?  Or are they interchangeable? Using the circuit below as an example.

[image]

\$KVL: 5 = V(t) + C*10000 \frac{dV(t)}{dt}\$ Around the right loop gives.

Re-writing to make the derivatives coefficient 1 gives:

\$ \frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{V}{C*10000} = \frac{5}{C*10000}\$

This makes  \$Tau = 10000 * (1*10^{-6})\$. For \$V_0(t->\infty)=5\$

Then I get \$V(t) = 5e^{-100t}\$

I just want some clarification on the process because I never feel like I do these correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best process that can follow, is to apply KVL and KCL**, as these are the most basic laws governing the behavior of a circuit, and therefore, are of general application and are used in all cases.

The application of the direct formula, may be useful in some cases, especially *those where the circuit is very simple*, such as a RC network used to delay a reset pulse.

However, applying KVL and KCL, it allows you to get the complete description of the circuit, considering its entirety, and after obtaining representation in the *time domain*, you can transform to the *frequency domain* and vice versa.

Under this view, it is desirable to have a good knowledge of the KVL and KCL as tools to find the equations describing a circuit.

**Edit: Analisys**

Since the excitation is a voltage source, the branch containing the resistor 2k does not influence the response, which is the voltage across the capacitor. KVL for the capacitor branch:

\$
5 = v_c(t) + i_R\cdot 10\,k\Omega
\$

since \$i_R=i_C\$ (series circuit)

\$
5 = v_c(t) + i_C\cdot 10\,k\Omega
\$

and from the V-I relationship for the capacitor

\$
5 = v_C(t) + C\cdot\dfrac{dv_C(t)}{dt}\cdot 10\,k\Omega
\$

arranging

\$
\dfrac{dv_C(t)}{dt}+\dfrac{1}{C\cdot 10\,k\Omega}\cdot v_C(t) = \dfrac{5}{C\cdot 10\,k\Omega}
\$

and here you make a mistake in your work. The solution for this differential equation is (assuming zero *initial conditions*)

\$
v_C(t) = 5\cdot\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{C\cdot 10\,k\Omega}}\right)
\$

you should try to solve the differential equation instead of estimating the constants, as in this case, mix both methods do not yield the correct result. Solve the equation is a bit more laborious, but you can control each step to determine the correct solution to a particular circuit.

Comment: If you have the time would you mind checking my work above?